# System is blocking acount deletion

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-accounts

I would like to delete my account permanently.  It seems your system is deliberately making account deletion a difficult task (to say the least).  I appreciate your prompt attention to deletion of my account, or I expect to be given an explanation by the legal department.

Comment: If I keep getting negative votes, will you (please) delete my account??

Answer (score 3):

Please see the Help page which explains how to do this.

https://english.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account

As there is a published process, please follow it.

Note that deleting your account does not delete any content you have posted, because you have licensed it to Stack Exchange, but that content will no longer be associated with your named account.

Comment: Yes I tried that.  But my "profile link" is not being accepted as valid.  Please advise.

Comment: You'll need to pursue that with the SE Team via email. I believe your profile link is http://english.stackexchange.com/users/106741/ellie (user 106741), if that helps.

Comment: I will try that.  Thank you for your help.  I appreciate it. Update: that was not accepted as my profile link, either. I will attempt to contact the SE Team.

Comment: I have been trying to delete my account for at least a week and have have emailed the SE team three times now with the required profile link. There does seem to be some delay even for folks who had no issues with the posted instructions.

Comment: My emails to the SE team have also gone unanswered.  Daniel, and others, following instructions DO NOT seem to be the issue here.

Comment: @Ellie I've raised it with The Powers That Be. As may be expected from having a contact form, there is a manual element to the process over which you have no control.

Answer (score 1):

You were trying to submit a deletion request from **meta**, using your **main site** profile link.

Try the main site contact form: https://english.stackexchange.com/contact

I've gone ahead and scheduled your account for deletion.